# How to show Wordpress when unauthenticated and the app when authenticated?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, domain, wordpress

So I'm trying to set up a website where the front-end (marketing) page is a wordpress site. Then when the user logs in, it redirects to my dotnet core web application.

An example of a site that does this is https://data.world. Here's the part that I'm confused about, I have a reverse proxy setup with apache like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  # ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName example.com
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}example-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}example-access.log common
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

So it redirects my url to my site, however, the authentication verification happens within my, how can I have my domain http://example.com, serve both wordpress (unauthenticated) and dotnet core app (authenticated)?

Comment: What does it mean to be authenticated? How could the web server tell the difference?

Comment: @MichaelHampton cookie vs no cookie